# Marbel word problem 3rd grade

Tags: word-problem

Leslie weighs her marbles in a jar, and the scale reads 474grams. The empty jar weighs 439 grams. Each marble weighs 5 grams. How many marbles are in the jar?

Comment: Who will answer it ?? I won't

Comment: I am terrible at math!! I tried 474-439=35x5=175

Comment: you should try 35/5=7

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help!